# What is the recommended way to install Postman?

Tags: software-installation, snap, snap-store

For Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 to install `Postman` mostly there are two options

- Through `Ubuntu Software` or `sudo snap install postman` (GUI or command)
- `.zip` file according with the official documentation at [Installing Postman on Linux](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation-and-updates/#installing-postman-on-linux)

Because the official page offers/indicates one approach

I want to know ***really*** what is the correct approach and the reason.

**Note**

According with the experience, for some software, when it is installed through `sudo apt instal xxx` - it is not always the latest release against the official page. So I don't know if it happens with `snap` too.

Comment: If you install from source, applying upgrading & security fixes is on you to perform. If you use a package (be it *snap*, *deb*, *flatpak*, *appimage* etc) it's dependent on the package type & method used and if you've provided sources to it.  *deb* packages will be release specific so if using the *latest* release (currently 23.04) you'll get the *latest*, if using something older you won't be (*usually!*).  *snap* package & other package types give you the same regardless of your OS/release (ie. 23.04 & 22.04 use the same depending on channel selected by installer). Best depends on your need

Comment: If using the *deb* format from default OS repositories, you'll have no issues with *release-upgrade* when that time comes... if you use a later source (eg. PPA) that may give newer software.. you'll may have problems come *release-upgrade* time... ie. What you're asking for is *opinion* where the best will be determined by your requirements (new vs. old software), how long you'll use the system (ie. *release-upgrade* is how big a concern for you in the future etc, or are you happy to resolve issues when that time comes) etc...  We have choice, pick best for your needs.

Comment: Consider to delete these 2 comments, they are already available on your answer ...

Comment: These comments relate to my *close vote*...  Yes I later copy/pasted & thus used them as an *answer*, but my close-vote remains.  Your question (*as written anyway*) would be better suited for a Forum; this is a Q&A site with https://ubuntuforums.org/ being the address of Ubuntu Forums.

Comment: @guiverc My general rule of thumb for close voting questions that have valuable answers that I might use for close voting other questions as duplicates of this question is to vote to leave them open.

Answer (score 2):

If you install from source, applying upgrading & security fixes is on you to perform. If you use a package (be it *snap*, *deb*, *flatpak*, *appimage* etc) it's dependent on the package type & method used and if you've provided sources to it.

*deb* packages will be release specific so if using the *latest* release (currently 23.04) you'll get the *latest*, if using something older (such as 22.04 which was 3 releases ago) you won't be (*usually!*).

*snap* package & other package types give you the same regardless of your OS/release (ie. 23.04 & 22.04 use the same *snap* package; though you can influence that too via channel selected by installer).

If using the *deb* format from default OS repositories, you'll have no issues with *release-upgrade* when that time comes... if you use a later source (eg. PPA) that may give newer software.. you'll may have problems come *release-upgrade* time... ie. What you're asking for is *opinion* where the best will be determined by your requirements (new vs. old software), how long you'll use the system (ie. *release-upgrade* is how big a concern for you in the future etc, or are you happy to resolve issues when that time comes) etc...

We have choice, pick best for your needs.

Comment: Otherwise or really anyway; I see the question as *off-topic* as you're seeking opinion, and what is *BEST* for one user/install will **not** be *best* for another user/install that will be used differently especially into the future.  What I do with one install often differs to what I select & use on other installs.

Comment: Just in case, the `.zip` file is not to build source code. For more details see this video about what consist the official approach - [How to install Postman App on Ubuntu 22.04 | Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp6qBCg5Y_I)

Comment: ZIP is just a form of *tarball* initially created so files stored on disk could be written to magnetic tape for backup.. There is no single standard for how to archive files in a ZIP (*or any tarball*) given the format is >40 years old there are many..  either way you're not talking about a method that has considered the *release-upgrade* process into the future as it cannot (*though that doesn't mean it won't work; depends on how careful the packager was as ~always*)